# Continuity, Differentiability and Tangents in a stepwise function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

**Question:**

Let

[image: question equation]

Sketch the graph of y = f(x). Does the tangent exist to f exist at x=1. Is f(x) differentiable x=1?

**My thoughts:**

As far as the graph is concerned, I think it should be a straight line at y=1, open at x=1 (y=0). I realise that the function is not continuous, based on the evaluation of the one-sided limits.

However, I am unable to deduce the existence of a tangent and whether or not it's differentiable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, continuity is a requisite for differentiability. Alternatively, try finding $f'(1)$ from the limit definition.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer That's what I thought too. So essentially, since the function isn't continuous, I can say that it's not differentiable, and therefore no tangent exists. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function is differentiable at a point of its domain, it's also continuous at that point. So, $f$ is not differentiable at $1$.

Concerning the existence of a tangent line, that depends upon which definition of tangent line you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it suffice to say that since a derivative at x=1 DNE, a tangent doesn't exist too?

Comment: Again, how do you define tangent line. The answer would be affirmative with respect to the definition that I use, but it may not be the same as yours.